# A question on deformation theory of triples of matrices

Tags: matrices, deformation-theory, eigenvalues

Let $(x,y,z)$ be a triple of $n \times n$ traceless complex matrices which are simultaneously diagonalizable. We call such a triple regular if $C_x \cap C_y \cap C_z$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$, where $C_x$ is the centralizer of $x$ in $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$, and so on. $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ acts diagonally via the Adjoint action on the set of such regular triples.

I am interested in the existence of a maximal holomorphic family of such regular triples which is transverse to the $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ orbits. In particular, does there exist a holomorphic family, transverse to the $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ orbits, which is parametrized by the manifold of $n$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{C}^3$ whose sum is the origin, quotiented out by the action of the symmetric group $S_n$ (those being the simultaneous eigenvalues of the triple, which are uniquely determined up to permutations).

I know there is a related paper by V. Arnold, but I don't have access to it. Does anyone happen to know the answer?

Comment: Just assume that $x, y$ and $z$ are diagonal, contained in the Cartan $\mathfrak{h}$. The condition of regularity means that they are not contained in a common root hyperplane, which is an open condition. So the universal family should be parametrised by the orbifold $[U/ W]$, where $U\subseteq \mathfrak{h}^3$ is an open subvariety and $W \cong \mathfrak{S}_{n-1}$ is the Weyl group, acting diagonally on $\mathfrak{h}^3$.

Comment: @Wille Liou, which theorem can one invoke to characterize the universal family as such please?

Comment: No theorem is needed. I just outlined a construction.  I first take a large family of triples in $\mathfrak{h}^3$ satisfying the regularity condition, parametrized by $U$. Then we identify those who are equivalent under the $\mathrm{SL}_n$ conjugation, which reduces to the Weyl group action on the Cartan.

Comment: @Wille Liou, yes but I am interested in families of triples, not of equivalence classes of triples. I guess my post needs some editing to make this clear.

Comment: @Wille Liou, I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand what the uniqueness means here. If you have such a maximal family transversal to the adjoint orbits, then so are its conjugates. On the other hand, any family can be conjugate to a pull-back from the one a just described.

Comment: @Wille Liou, you are right. I am mostly interested in the existence. I edited the post.